# String method is returning null

Tags: java, string, methods

I am trying to teach my self Java programming, coming from a Python and MatLab background. In my code below, the first set of code returns what it should when using the default constructor I defined. However in the second set of code when I try using a specific constructor the result is "null null null". I am trying to understand why the specific constructor is returning null null null and how I can remedy this.

First Code segment:

```
public class Name {

   String firstName; 
   String middleName; 
   String familyName; 

   public Name() {

      firstName = " ";
      middleName = " ";
      familyName = " ";

    }

    public Name(String firstName, String middleName, String familyName) { 
       setFirst(firstName); 
       setMiddle(middleName); 
       setFamily(familyName); 
    }

   // setFirst(): first name mutator method
   public void setFirst(String f) { 
      String firstName = f; 
    }

    // setMiddle(): middle name mutator method
    public void setMiddle(String m) { 
      String middleName = m; 
    }

    // setFamily(): family name mutator method
    public void setFamily(String fam) { 
      String familyName = fam; 
    }


    // getFirst(): accessor method
    public String getFirst() {
       return firstName; 
    }

    // getMiddle(): accessor method
    public String getMiddle() {
       return middleName; 
    }

    // getFamily(): accessor method   
    public String getFamily() {
       return familyName;
    }

    // toString(): mutator method
    public String toString() { 
       return getFirst() + " " + getMiddle() + " " + getFamily(); 
    }




   public static void main(String[] args) { 

      Name myName = new Name(); 
      String myNameString = myName.toString(); 
      System.out.print("\n" + myNameString); 
   }
}
```

Second Code Segment:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) { 

      Name myName = new Name("John", "Doe", "Smith"); 
      String myNameString = myName.toString(); 
      System.out.print("\n" + myNameString); 
   }
}
```

Comment: You're not setting the fields defined at instance level.

Comment: you are declaring a new varible in set methods instead do `this.propertyName` etc

Comment: in setFirst method that you called from constructor, you are assigning the firstname to new variable firstName which has scope of only method setFirst. You need to assign that variable to the current instance  like this  this.firstName=f;

Comment: To me it looks like your public Name() being used twice may be causing some issues. There are methods all over the place. You may want to learn more about Methods and how to use them more(here is a great site to learn):  http://www.dotnetperls.com/method-java

Comment: FYI toString is not a mutator as it does not change the state of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Your various setter methods are not setting the class members they are just setting local variables. Change setFirst to this:

```
   public void setFirst(String f) { 
      this.firstName = f; 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You declare new local variables (with same name as the member) in your setter methods:

```
String familyName = fam;
```

Just write:

```
familyName = fam;
```

It's good practice to prefix either members (e.g. by "my") in order to distinguish it from local variables. And I suggest to use a sophisticated IDE which would have warned you that you declare a local variable with the same name as a member.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setMiddle(String m) { 
  String middleName = m; 
}
```

This is just creating a new object called middleName in memory.

To set the value on middleName field you should not create a new object, but reference the field:

```
public void setMiddle(String m) { 
   middleName = m; 
}
```